# How can I include additional modules in a NodeJS custom binary?

Tags: node.js

I am building a custom binary of NodeJS from the latest code base for an embedded system. I have a couple modules that I would like to ship as standard with the binary - or even run a custom script the is compiled into the binary and can be invoked through a command line option.

So two questions:

1) I vaguely remember that node allowed to include custom modules during build time but I went through the latest 5.9.0 configure script and I can't see anything related - or maybe I am missing it.

2) Did someone already do something similar? If yes, what were the best practices you came up with?

I am not looking for something like Electron or other binary bundlers but actually building into the node binary.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I figure it out much faster that I thought.

For anyone else, you can add any NPM module to it and just add the actual source files to the `node.gyp` configuration file.

Compile it and run the custom binary. It's all in there now.

```
> var cmu = require("cmu");
undefined
> cmu
{ version: [Function] }
> cmu.version()
'It worked!'
> `
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of the node.gyp modification? Can I really add ANY npm module? It seems to me that all the files in /src are internal modules which behave slightly different than normal dynamically linked npm modules. Also what if the module consists of both native and javascript files? Thanks...

Comment: Also what if the module being added has it's own dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

After studying this for quite a while, I have to say that the flyandi's answer is not quite true. You cannot add **any** NPM module just by adding it to the node.gyp.

You can only add pure JavaScript modules this way. To be able to embed a C++ module (I deliberately don't use the word "native", because that one is quite ambiguous in nodeJS terminology - just look at the sources).

To summarize this:

To embed a JS module to your custom nodejs, just add it in the `library_files` section of the node.gyp file. Also note that it should be placed within the lib folder, otherwise you'll have troubles requiring the module. That's because the name/path listed in node.gyp / library_files is used to encode the id of the module in the node_javascript.cc intermediate file which is then used when searching for the built-in modules.

To embed a native module is much more difficult. The best way I have found so far is to build the module as a static library instead of dynamic, which for cmake(-js) based module you can achieve by changing the SHARED parameter to STATIC like this:

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC})
```

instead of:

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC})
```

And also changing the suffix:

```
set_target_properties(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PROPERTIES
  PREFIX "" 
  SUFFIX ".lib") /* instead of .node */
```

Then you can link it from node.gyp by adding this section:

```
'link_settings': {
    'libraries' : [ 
      "path/to/my/library.lib",
      #...add other static dependencies
    ],
},
```

(how to do this with node-gyp based project should be quite ease to google)

This allows you to build the module, but you won't be able to require it, because require() function in node can only be used to load built-in JS modules, external JS modules or external dynamic node modules. But now we have a built-in C++ module. Well, lot of node integrated modules are C++, but they always have a JS wrapper in `/lib`, and those wrappers they use `process.binding()` to load the C++ module. That is, `process.binding()` is sort of a `require()` function for integrated C++ modules.

That said, we also need to call `require.binding()` instead of require to load our integrated module. To be able to do that, we have to make our module "built-in" first.

We can do that by replacing

```
NODE_MODULE(mymodule, InitAll)
```

int the module definition with

```
NODE_BUILTIN_MODULE_CONTEXT_AWARE(mymodule, InitAll)
```

which will register it as internal module and from now on we can `process.binding()` it.

Note that `NODE_BUILTIN_MODULE_CONTEXT_AWARE` is not defined in `node.h` as `NODE_MODULE` but in `node_internals.h` so you either have to include that one, or copy the macro definition over to your cpp file (the first one is of course better because the nodejs API tends to change quite often...).

The last thing we need to do is to list our newly integrated module among the others so that the node knows to initialize them (that is include them within the list of modules used when searching for the modules loaded with `process.binding()`). In node_internals.h there is this macro:

```
#define NODE_BUILTIN_STANDARD_MODULES(V)                                      \
    V(async_wrap)                                                             \
    V(buffer)                                                                 \
    V(cares_wrap)                                                             \
...
```

So just add the your module to the list the same way as the others `V(mymodule)`.

I might have forgotten some step, so ask in the comments if you think I have missed something.

If you wonder why would anyone even want to do this... You can come up with several reasons, but here's one most important to me: Those package managers used to pack your project within one executable (like pkg or nexe) work only with node-gyp based modules. If you, like me, need to use cmake based module, the final executable won't work...